# layout NestedScrollView with RecyclerView results in huge decrease in performance

Tags: android

I'm using NestedScrollView in my app in order to have the Toolbar hide when scrolling on a RecyclerView. The problem is when I put the RecyclerView inside the NestedScrollView the performance of the RecyclerView is very bad, taking long to load and stuttering when scrolling.

Here's my xml implementation of the fragment with the RecyclerView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:background="@color/light_gray"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:clickable="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is fragment goes inside a ViewPager. Here's the other layout with the ViewPager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_below="@id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"/>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/eventsProgress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/search_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Removing the NestedScrollView and leaving the RecyclerView alone results in much better performance but then I don't have the hiding toolbar.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you use `CoordinatorLayout` somewhere? Is this layout part of another one or is it standalone?

Comment: Yes, sorry. This layout is for fragments that go inside a ViewPager. I have added more information and the layout with the ViewPager.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try `CoordinatorLayout` with `AppBar` for `Toolbar`. In that way using correct scrollBehavior you can hide/collapse Toolbar when list is scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

When you put a recycler view inside scrollview, by default scrollview scrolling works not the recycler view scrolling.
To fix it you can try `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"` for recyclerView.
Hope this fix your problem.

Comment: I already call setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) in the fragment

Comment: set it true... :P